# hp proliant microserver not detecting hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, hp, bios

So, I've hit a bit of a wall with the HP Proliant Microserver N40L. I'm trying to install a new hard drive, 4 TB, but it's not being detected by the BIOS and thus, not the OS either. It just spins up, and that's it. Changing the modes in the BIOS, IDE and AHCI, doesn't work. Every other drive picks up fine. I tried switching slots with them, but that doesn't work either.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the disk in other systems?

Comment: yep, the disk works fine in other systems.

Comment: Have you tried running the system in a supported configuration or are you just determined to hack about in an unprofessional way - it might be worth you reading the first line of our help files to remind yourself what this site is and isn't for.

Comment: Some guidelines on how to go about this more professionally would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the following link http://n40l.wikia.com/wiki/Hard_drives it shows that 4TB disks can work on the N40L, however not all makes/models.

I use 2TB disks in my N40L without issue.

Suggestions would be:

1. Check firmware for the disks, see if there are upgrades available (read release notes carefully)
2. Check firmware for your N40L, maybe this needs an update since it is quite an old model. 4TB didn't exist when it was released so later bios updates may bring in some extra capabilities. (again read release notes carefully)

Either way, you could be looking at flashing firmware, so please be EXTREMELY careful and make yourself aware of the consequences of a failed firmware update.

Comment: Will try this and report back.